# Incorrect S3 bucket policy is detected for bucket in Boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudtrail

I have been working on setting up CloudTrail for an IAM user using Boto but I have run into an error:

> An error occurred (InsufficientS3BucketPolicyException) when calling the CreateTrail operation: Incorrect S3 bucket policy is detected for bucket: goodbucket

I am not sure what's wrong here. Saving the CloudTrail log is not a priority but I will need ResourceID, to delete resource later on using Lambda functions.

```py
    import boto3
    import sys
    import json
    import time 
    iam = boto3.client('iam')
    sts = boto3.client('sts')
    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
    cloudtrail = boto3.client('cloudtrail')
    
    response = iam.create_user(
        UserName='GoodUser'
    )
    IDK = sts.get_caller_identity()
    print(IDK['UserId'])
    response = iam.create_group(
        GroupName='GoodGroup'
    )
    
    response = iam.add_user_to_group(
        GroupName='GoodGroup',
        UserName='GoodUser'
    )
    
    some_policy = {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
                "Resource": [
                    f"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:{IDK['Account']}:instance/*",
                    f"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:{IDK['Account']}:network-interface/*",
                    f"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:{IDK['Account']}:key-pair/*",
                    f"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:{IDK['Account']}:security-group/*",
                    f"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:{IDK['Account']}:subnet/*",
                    f"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:{IDK['Account']}:volume/*",
                    f"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:{IDK['Account']}:image/ami-0a91cd140a1fc148a"
                ],
                "Condition": {
                    "ForAllValues:NumericLessThanEquals": {
                        "ec2:VolumeSize": "10"
                    },
                    "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                        "ec2:InstanceType": "t2.micro"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "ec2:TerminateInstances",
                    "ec2:StartInstances",
                    "ec2:StopInstances"
                ],
                "Resource": f"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:{IDK['Account']}:instance/*",
                "Condition": {
                    "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                        "ec2:InstanceType": "t2.micro"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "ec2:Describe*",
                    "ec2:GetConsole*",
                    "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms",
                    "iam:ListInstanceProfiles",
                    "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics",
                    "ec2:DescribeKeyPairs",
                    "ec2:CreateKeyPair"
                ],
                "Resource": "*",
                "Condition": {
                    "DateGreaterThan": {
                        "aws:CurrentTime": "2020-12-10T05:00:00Z"
                    },
                    "DateLessThanEquals": {
                        "aws:CurrentTime": "2020-12-10T05:35:00Z"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    } 
    response = iam.create_policy(
      PolicyName='GoodPolicy',
      PolicyDocument=json.dumps(some_policy)
    )
    print(response)
    
    IDK1 = iam.attach_group_policy(
        GroupName='GoodGroup',
        PolicyArn= f"arn:aws:iam::{IDK['Account']}:policy/GoodPolicy"
    )
    
    logs = cloudtrail.create_trail(
        Name='GoodTrail',
        S3BucketName='goodbucket',
    )
    print (logs)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are configuring AWS CloudTrail to write log files to an Amazon S3 bucket. To do this, the S3 bucket requires a **Bucket Policy** that grants permission to the CloudTrail service to write to the bucket.

From [Amazon S3 Bucket Policy for CloudTrail - AWS CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/create-s3-bucket-policy-for-cloudtrail.html):

> If you want to create or modify an Amazon S3 bucket to receive the log files for an organization trail, you must further modify the bucket policy.
>
> To deliver log files to an S3 bucket, CloudTrail must have the required permissions, and it cannot be configured as a Requester Pays bucket. CloudTrail automatically attaches the required permissions to a bucket when you create an Amazon S3 bucket as part of creating or updating a trail in the CloudTrail console.

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {"Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"},
            "Action": "s3:GetBucketAcl",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myBucketName"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {"Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"},
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myBucketName/[optional prefix]/AWSLogs/myAccountID/*",
            "Condition": {"StringEquals": {"s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"}}
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This might not work because I am trying to create IAM identity-based policy and I cannot use the Principal element in an IAM identity-based policy

Comment: CloudTrail requires a bucket policy, not an IAM policy. Otherwise, it can't write the logs to the bucket.